# Create Webbrowser in new thread and paint it on form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using this code to create a web browser control in new thread:

```
void Exec(string url)
        {
            var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
                {
                    wb.DocumentCompleted += (sndr, e) =>
                    {
                        // Do something when completed
                        wb.Dispose();
                        Application.ExitThread();
                    };
                    wb.Navigate(url);
                    Application.Run();
                }
            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
            th.Join();
        }
```

Now every time I call this method, it will create new instance of the web browser control.
My question is if it's possible to paint/re-paint the control on a form, when new instance is created?

Comment: Is this WinForms, or Silverlight?

Comment: My guess would be that the simple answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Might be optimized though.

```
        void Exec(string url)
        {
            var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
                {
                    wb.Name = "webBrowserGenerated" + Guid.NewGuid();
                    List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
                    GetAllControl(this, list);
                    foreach (Control control in list)
                    {
                        if (control.GetType() == typeof(WebBrowser))
                        {
                            if (control.Name.StartsWith("webBrowserGenerated"))
                            {
                                control.Refresh();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    wb.DocumentCompleted += (sndr, e) =>
                    {
                        // Do something when completed
                        wb.Dispose();
                        Application.ExitThread();
                    };
                    wb.Navigate(url);
                    Application.Run();
                }
            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
            th.Join();
        }

    private void GetAllControl(Control c, List<Control> list)
    {
        foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
        {
            list.Add(control);
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                GetAllControl(control, list);
        }
    }
```